# Convertir modelo en otro modelo con List

Tags: c#

Dispongo de dos modelos idénticos:

**Modelo 1**

```
public class Modelo
{
    public string IdModelo { get; set; }
    public List<DatosModelo> Datos { get; set; }
}

public class DatosModelo
{
    public string IdModelo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Modelo 2**

```
public class ModeloBD
{
    public string IdModelo { get; set; }
    public List<DatosModeloBD> Datos { get; set; }
}

public class DatosModeloBD
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Para convertir el modelo 2 al modelo 1 he intentado con:

```
List<ModeloBD> data = _svcConfiguracion.GetOperaciones(4);
List<Modelo> transformar = data.Select(ToVm());

public Modelo ToVm(ModeloBD modelo)
{
    return new Modelo
    {
        IdModelo = modelo.IdModelo,
        Datos = modelo.Datos.Select(ToVm) // Intento aqui realizar la transformacion de la lista de datos y falla
    };
}

public DatosModelo ToVm(DatosModeloBD datos)
{
    return new DatosModelo
    {
        Title = datos.Title,
        Value = datos.Value
    };
}
```

**¿Existe una manera para realizarlo sin tener que dividirlo?**

Comment: ¿porque no usas linq? `Datos = modelo.Datos.Select(x => new DatosModelo {//seteas propiedades})`, eso debería funcionar sin ningún problema, sino, también podes usar alguna librería como Automapper

Comment: Creo que también te podría funcionar un "explicit operator": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mejor forma de convertir estructuras de datos es usando la libreria `AutoMapper`

[AutoMapper nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/)

con esta librerias podrias definir como se convierten las entidades

[Getting Started Guide](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html)

entonces defines el mapping

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ModeloBD, Modelo>();
    cfg.CreateMap<DatosModeloBD, DatosModelo>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

List<ModeloBD> data = _svcConfiguracion.GetOperaciones(4);

var transformar = mapper.Map<List<ModeloBD>, List<Modelo>>(data);
```

papra poder usar el `Map<>()` y convertir de un tipo a otro mapeado

Comment: ¿Porqué dices que "la mejor"?. Esto es muy relativo, me parece.

Comment: la mejor en el sentido que esta optimizado para esa tarea y permite convertir estructuras complejas con practicamente poco codigo, esta claro que hay otras alternativas como usar linq, pero deberias escribir muchisimo mas para pasar los datos de una propiedad a otra